# Limiting number of related posts

Tags: wp-query, categories, limit

I'm trying to add a related posts section to the bottom of my single post views.  It needs to grab the categories of the current post and show just 2 posts that match any of those categories.  I'm almost there, but my results are showing 2 from each category as opposed to a total of 2.

```
<?php if ( is_single() ) { ?>
    <div class="related-posts wrapper clearfix">
        <?php $categories = get_the_category();
            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                $cat = $category->cat_ID;
                $args=array(
                    'cat' => $cat,
                    'order' =>DESC,
                    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
                    'posts_per_page'=>2,
                );
            $my_query = null;
            $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
            if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                $i = 0; while ($my_query->have_posts() && $i < 3) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <h2 class="related-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <?php  $i++; endwhile; }
            }
            wp_reset_query();
        ?>
    </div>
<?php } else {};?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build an array of categories:

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $cat[] = $category->cat_ID;
}
```

Then pass that to the query:

```
$args=array(
  'category__in' => $cat, 
  'order' =>DESC, 
  'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
  'posts_per_page'=>2, 
);
```

In other words, put the query after the `foreach`, not inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

`$i` is being reset for each category.

Try declaring $i before the foreach cat loop:

```
<?php 
$i = 0; 
$categories = get_the_category();
// etc
```

And if `$i = 0`, then you will get 3 posts before it stops, so try this:

```
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      while ($my_query->have_posts() && $i < 2)
      // etc
```